# creating table with primary key and 2 foreign keys with error

Tags: mysql, constraints

I'm trying to create a table that has a composite PK constraint using Rep_ID, Store_ID, and Quarter and I'm trying to create a FK constraint on Rep_ID and Store_ID

This is my statement:

`CREATE TABLE REP_CONTRACTS(
Store_ID INT(8),
Name INT(5),
Quarter CHAR(3),
Rep_ID INT(5),
PRIMARY KEY (Rep_ID, Store_ID, Quarter),
Rep_ID INT REFERENCES BOOK_STORES(Rep_ID),
Store_ID INT REFERENCES BOOK_STORES(Store_ID)
);`

These are my tables:

Book Stores:

`Column Name    Datatype    Constraint Comments
Store_ID         INT(8)       PRIMARY KEY column
Name            VARCHAR(30)   Should be UNIQUE and NOT NULL
Contact          VARCHAR(20)
Rep_ID            INT(5)`

Rep Contracts

`Column Name     DataType
Store_ID          INT(8)
Name              INT(5)
Quarter           CHAR(3)
Rep_ID            INT(5)`

I have already created the book store table, I'm trying to create the rep contracts table

I also get the error `Duplicate column name 'Rep_ID'. Add a differentiating column alias.` when running this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are declaring REPID twice in the table, which is why you are getting the duplication error. You may also want to create the column "Store ID" before using it in the Primary Key Statement.

```
CREATE TABLE REP_CONTRACTS(
Store_ID INT(8),
Name INT(5),
Quarter CHAR(3),
Rep_ID INT(5) REFERENCES BOOK_STORES(Rep_ID),
Store_ID INT REFERENCES BOOK_STORES(Store_ID),
PRIMARY KEY (Rep_ID, Store_ID, Quarter)
);
```